# Rails query not returning expected number of records when I add another conditional within Where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models: `Call` and `County`.

```
#app/models/call.rb
class Call < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :county
end

#app/models/county.rb
class County < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :calls
end
```

This query works wonderfully:

```
# @calls is only some selection of calls, not ALL of the calls  
@calls = Call.only_grab_some_calls 
@calls_by_county_query = County.includes(:calls).where("calls.id IN (?)", @calls.pluck(:id)).references(:calls)
```

Basically, I am grabbing only counties associated to any of the calls within `@calls`, and then I am eager loading all of those `@calls`.

Now: Some of those calls within that `@calls` collection have `county_id = nil`.  They have no county listed.  I want to be able to grab those ones too.  No errors are thrown for my query below, but `@calls_by_nil_county_query.size` is displaying `0` when I know it should be displaying `3`.

```
@calls = Call.only_grab_some_calls 
@calls_by_nil_county_query = County.includes(:calls).where(["calls.id IN (?) AND calls.county_id = ?", @calls.pluck(:id), nil]).references(:calls)
```

Something is off about my query once I add that other conditional.  Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What is the desired end result because your first query grabs calls regardless of association to counties and the second will only return counties with the calls in the original eager loaded. This is an INNER JOIN so county_id = nil will be ignored. An OUTER JOIN would work for this but I am not sure how that would be identified in the AR object since the second call will return counties and nil is not a county. If you know the exact data you want you could create a transformation of sorts where if the county_id is null then the county is Unknown but you have to describe the desired result set

Comment: You should be able to do this in reverse though like `Call.only_grab_some_calls.eager_load(:county)` then the calls will have access to the county as an OUTER JOIN so county will be nil when county_id is null (Make sure to handle this in the view though).

Comment: @engineersmnky ah-ha!  you set me on the right path.  The answer is to simply do this: `@calls_by_nil_county_query = @calls.where(county_id: nil)` .I was making it too complicated.  If you could post this as the answer I will give you credit since you helped me.

Comment: I am glad I could help. Since I still do not understand the full concept of what you were/are trying to accomplish I feel answering the question would not be appropriate. I generally will only answer questions that I understand the full requirements and expectations (I am here to help people more than to accumulate frivolous reputation points) As long as you are happy with the result of my comment that is enough for me.  Best of Luck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making the query too complicated.  Here is how you can do it:

```
@calls_by_nil_county_query = @calls.where(county_id: nil)
```